# Vuetify - Unable to display data in table via typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Forgive me for the question, I am a beginner with Vuetify and Typescript in general. I have been trying to render a Vuetify data table, using data populated from a typescript file that gets data from an API, as seen below. However, I cannot seem to get the data. From postman, the API calls work. I am basing an experiment off of https://dev.to/andynoir/draggable-table-row-with-vuejs-vuetify-and-sortablejs-1o7l

```
<template>
  <main class="page page--table">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="tableHeaders"
      :items="tableItems"
      item-key="id"
      :show-select="false"
      :disable-pagination="true"
      :hide-default-footer="true"
      class="page__table"
      dark
    >
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <draggable
          :list="props.items"
          tag="tbody"
        >
          <tr
            v-for="(user, index) in props.items"
            :key="index"
          >
            <td>
              <v-icon
                small
                class="page__grab-icon"
              >
                mdi-arrow-all
              </v-icon>
            </td>
            <td> {{ user.id }} </td>
            <td> {{ user.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ user.description }} </td>
            <td>
              <v-icon
                small
                @click="editUser(user.id)"
              >
                mdi-pencil
              </v-icon>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </main>
</template>
```

This is how the typescript file looks like:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Draggable from 'vuedraggable';
import { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios';
import api from '@/api';
import { User } from '@/types/user.interface';

@Component({
  components: {
    Draggable,
  },
})
export default class PageTable extends Vue {
  private tableItems: User[] = []

  private tableHeaders = [
    // { text: '', sortable: false },
    { text: 'ID', value: 'id', sortable: false },
    { text: 'NAME', value: 'name', sortable: false },
    { text: 'DESCRIPTION', value: 'description', sortable: false },
  ];

  private editUser(userId: number) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'PageEdit', params: { id: `${userId}` } });
  }

  public async fetchAllUsers() {
    this.loading = true;
    await api
      .get('/users')
      .then((data: AxiosResponse) => {
        const computedArrayOfUsers = data.data.map((user: User) => ({
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          description: user.description,
        }));
        this.tableItems = computedArrayOfUsers;
      })
      .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }

  created() {
    this.fetchAllUsers();
  }
}
</script>
```

I have been trying to put the user data into an array, so I could put it in the table. This how the types/user.interface file looks like

```
export interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

And this is the index file

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://myownlink.com/',
});

export default api;
```

The JSON body of the API, when called with a GET method via postman, shows this:

```
{
    "id": "12345678",
    "name": "User Test",
    "description": "Description Test",
}
```

Is there something that I am missing to get the data?

Comment: Do you get any errors during render?

Comment: I do not @Fabalance